# Invalid word list returned by Word

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

In an Word addin, I'm using

```
this.Application.ActiveDocument.Words;
```

to get a list of all the words in the curret document. Now when I parse this list, I found the `,`, `.` and `\r` are also in this list. Why is Word considering these words? I also looked at the word count in the status bar and that was wrong too, as for 7 words in my document the status bar shows 9 words.

Comment: It would help if you could supply a sample document (e.g. The 7 or 9 word document) and some sample code

Comment: Seems to be by design: "Punctuation and paragraph marks in a document are included in the Words collection."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb216304%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's a feature.

from:
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224332%28office.11%29.aspx)

*Note  Punctuation and paragraph marks in a document are included in the Words collection.*

also found:

```
If SingleWord < "A" Or SingleWord > "z" Then SingleWord = "" 'Out of range?
```

[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/worddev/thread/8ddb02da-d954-40f4-b4a5-403fa8fa5a69)

which says to me you can exclude punctuation from your set by testing for 'words' less than A or greater than z.

Comment: is there a way to tell word to return words that ar not puntuation. This is important because it takes very very long to access all words including putuation by index and test if they are words or puctuation before use them. So if a smaler list is returned containing only words --> les time.

Comment: don't think so, or didn't see it.  just saw where others are limiting the list of words after word returns it.